# Solve "CommandNotFoundException" error in powershell , the script is deleted from that location?

Tags: powershell, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

> : The term
> 'C:\Users\rapula\lib\oracle-cli\Lib\site-packages\oci_cli\bin\OciTabExpansion.ps1'
> is not recognized as
> the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
> included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
> At C:\Users\rapula\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1:1
> char:3
> + . C:\Users\rapula\lib\oracle-cli\Lib\site-packages\oci_cli\bin\OciTab
> ...
> +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\rapula...abExpansion.ps1:String) [],
> CommandNotFoundException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

The script is manually removed from system , but error persists. Please suggest how to remove this default message error.

Comment: "the script is manually removed from system", well, that would explain the error - PowerShell can't execute a script that isn't there

Comment: Thank you Mathias R Jesson. I removed the path from system profile file and the error is removed upon startup.thank you for your response and time.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the file path from the system profile file of windows powershell.ps1.and the error is removed upon start of powershell.